# usar apollo client por fuera de un componente

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

necesito ayuda para hacer una query GraphQL con apollo-client pero no
desde un componente react, es desde un archivo Javscript normal, cuando hacía la llamada desde un componente usaba:

```
useLazyQuery(QUERYDOCUMENT)
```

Pero lo que quiero hacer me da error, ya que useQuery y useLazyQuery requieren que sean llamados dentro de un componente react.

Como podria hacer la query?

Answer (score 0):

Para usarlo hay que crear una instancia del cliente Apollo, de esta manera:

```
    import {
      ApolloClient,
      InMemoryCache,
      NormalizedCacheObject,
      gql,
    } from '@apollo/client'
    
    export const myApolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient(
      {
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        ssrMode: true,
        uri: 'graphql-api-url',
      }
    )

crear la query/mutation con "gql", ejemplo:

const GETDOCUMENT = gql`
  query getDocuments($where: String, $fields: [String]) {
    documents(where: $where, fields: $fields) {
      id
      fields {
        key
        value
      }
    }
  }
`
```

y finalmente usar el cliente para hacer la llamada, en el caso de abajo, una query:

```
     const getData= async (variable: string) => {
      const result = await primeUserClient.query({
        variables: {
          where: `conditions`,
          fields: ['field_1', 'field-2'],
        },
        query: GETDOCUMENT,
      })
      return result
   }
```